# ExtJS 4 Grid Panel - Spacebar row toggle

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In ExtJS 4, selecting a row in a Grid Panel (by clicking it), and pressing the spacebar selects and de-selects the row.  It was not like this in ExtJS 3, and I would like to disable this feature.

Any ideas?  I've begin looking into `Ext.util.KeyMap` to see if I could override it somehow.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override the `onKeyPress` method of the `Ext.selection.RowModel`. The shipped implementation is

```
onKeyPress: function(e, t) {
    if (e.getKey() === e.SPACE) {
        e.stopEvent();
        var me = this,
            record = me.lastFocused;

        if (record) {
            if (me.isSelected(record)) {
                me.doDeselect(record, false);
            } else {
                me.doSelect(record, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there currently is no configuration switch to turn off that behavior.

Comment: There is configuration `enableKeyNav` which allows turning off key navigation in `Ext.selection.RowModel`

Comment: Yes there is, but that also switches off all other keyboard navigation as well - such as cursor keys, page up and down, home and end.

Comment: @Molecule, thanks for the response, `enableKeyNav` might actually work better for me in the long run.