# How to override Ext.selection.RowModel in ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

In ExtJS 4 they introduced space bar toggle selection on a grid panel. I want to be able to override the onKeyPress and disable this. (I do not want to disable enableKeyNav)

What I've tried;

```
//This didn't work....
Ext.override('Ext.selection.RowModel', {
    onKeyPress: function(e, t) {
      console.log(e);
    }
});
//This also didn't work...
Ext.define('MyApp.selection.RowModel', {
  override: 'Ext.selection.RowModel',
  onKeyPress: function(e, t) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

Related topic; [ExtJS 4 Grid Panel - Spacebar row toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791366/extjs-4-grid-panel-spacebar-row-toggle)

The source code that I want to override;

```
// Select/Deselect based on pressing Spacebar.
// Assumes a SIMPLE selectionmode style
onKeyPress: function(e, t) {
    if (e.getKey() === e.SPACE) {
        e.stopEvent();
        var me = this,
        record = me.lastFocused;

        if (record) {
            if (me.isSelected(record)) {
                me.doDeselect(record, false);
            } else {
                me.doSelect(record, true);
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: The second one looks ok, but timing could be an issue. When are you overriding it?

Comment: At the end of the application entry point. So at the end of Ext.application

I'm using Architect so when I tried the second one, the grid flat out didn't load. I changed the 'createClass' property of the Selection Model to MyApp.selection.RowModel but yeah it throws an error which can't be traced in chrome tools

Comment: Actually the errror is Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function VM13736:3
(anonymous function) VM13736:3
Ext.ClassManager.instantiate ext-all.js:9273
(anonymous function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems onKeyPress doesn't exist in 4.2.2 which is what I was using.

Ended up going with...

```
Ext.define('MyApp.selection.RowModel', {
  override: 'Ext.selection.RowModel',
  onKeySpace: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

Source: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/RowModel.html